# Custom EditText in android

Tags: android

I am trying to create a Edit text view in android, with arrow at Right. when i type something inside edit text , arrow should appear , and if i click that arrow , it should perform some action . Im able to place arrow using  android:drawableLeft="@drawable/arrow" . How  can i make it interactive . Please help me in this ASAP .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant perform Click action on Drawable instead you should have a Relative layout containing EditText and Button such as it appears inside EditText. Refer the below Layout XML

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/searchEditText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:hint="Search">
    </EditText>
    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/clearSearchbtn"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center" android:background="@drawable/close"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_marginRight="10px">
    </Button>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi , I came up wit a problem. If i type long text then its writing on image too.. how can i avoid this